# C# Transactions on Oracle & SQL Server via ADO.NET failing

Tags: c#, oracle, sql-server-2008, ado.net, transactions

I have written a class in C# that is intended to offer the ability to run database transactions on a given database connection. When I try to run the code however I get the following two errors on Oracle and SQL Server respectively. Looking at my code is there an easy way around this?

**Oracle**

> *Connection is already part of a local or a distributed transaction*

**SQL Server 2008**

> *SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions*

**The base class**

```
  public abstract class DbFactoryDatabaseTransaction
  {
    public void DoTransaction(IDatabaseConnectivityObjectBasicResponse databaseConnectivityObject)
    {
        databaseConnectivityObject.PrepareConnection();

        DbTransaction dbTransaction = databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseConnection.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {
            ExecuteSql(databaseConnectivityObject, dbTransaction);

            dbTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            dbTransaction.Rollback();

            databaseConnectivityObject.Close();

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            dbTransaction.Dispose();
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// A method to allow the caller to decide how the SQL statements are called as part of a transaction
    /// </summary>
    public abstract void ExecuteSql(IDatabaseConnectivityObjectBasicResponse databaseConnectivityObject, DbTransaction dbTransaction);
}
```

**The override method**

```
public override void ExecuteSql(IDatabaseConnectivityObjectBasicResponse databaseConnectivityObject, DbTransaction dbTransaction)
    {
        //oracle
        List<string> transactions = new List<string>
            {
                "INSERT INTO TMA_NOT_TO_ENTITY_QUEUE (RECEIVED_NOTICE_ID, NOTICE_TEXT, STATE_ID, TIME_RECEIVED) VALUES (1, 'This is a notice', 1, to_date('2012/08/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))",
                "INSERT INTO TMA_NOT_TO_ENTITY_QUEUE (RECEIVED_NOTICE_ID, NOTICE_TEXT, STATE_ID, TIME_RECEIVED) VALUES (2, 'This is a notice', 1, to_date('2012/08/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))",
                "INSERT INTO TMA_NOT_TO_ENTITY_QUEUE (RECEIVED_NOTICE_ID, NOTICE_TEXT, STATE_ID, TIME_RECEIVED) VALUES (3, 'This is a notice', 1, to_date('2012/08/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))",
                "INSERT INTO TMA_NOT_TO_ENTITY_QUEUE (RECEIVED_NOTICE_ID, NOTICE_TEXT, STATE_ID, TIME_RECEIVED) VALUES (4, 'This is a notice', 1, to_date('2012/08/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))",
                "INSERT INTO TMA_NOT_TO_ENTITY_QUEUE (RECEIVED_NOTICE_ID, NOTICE_TEXT, STATE_ID, TIME_RECEIVED) VALUES (5, 'This is a notice', 1, to_date('2012/08/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))",
                "INSERT INTO TMA_NOT_TO_ENTITY_QUEUE (RECEIVED_NOTICE_ID, NOTICE_TEXT, STATE_ID, TIME_RECEIVED) VALUES (6, 'This is a notice', 1, to_date('2012/08/15', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))"
            };

        databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.Transaction = databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseConnection.BeginTransaction();

        foreach (var transaction in transactions)
        {
            databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.CommandText = transaction;
            databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.Transaction = dbTransaction;
            databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

**The calling method**

```
    public void RunTransaction()
        {
        IDatabaseConnectivityObjectBasicResponse databaseConnectivityObject = new DbProviderFactoryConnectionBasic();

        DoTransaction(databaseConnectivityObject);
        }
```

**The test method**

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void RunTransactionTest()
    {
        TmaNoticeToClusteredEntityValidation target = new TmaNoticeToClusteredEntityValidation(BindVariables, SqlFactory, Dialect); 
        target.RunTransaction();
        Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot be verified.");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was actually that I was calling BeginTransaction twice() on the connection object. This was solved by removing `databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.Transaction = databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseConnection.BeginTransaction();`
from the override method.

Answer (score 0):

Just omit this line on override

```
databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.Transaction = databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseConnection.BeginTransaction();
```

And change this

```
databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.Transaction = dbTransaction;
```

To

```
databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseCommand.Connection= databaseConnectivityObject.DBFactoryDatabaseConnection;
```